# Mysql find max within a dated range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a decent query working now but I need to find the max out of the results. The rssi field.
table layout
id - rssi, item, datetime

My query now is

```sql
select 
      id, rssi 
from 
      table 
where 
      item = 1 and dt > date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute)
```

I have tried several other answers from around here and they work fine if I do not use the date part but I want to run the query only on the latest entries.

Comment: Sample data and desired result will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the most recent row:

```
select id, rssi 
from table 
where item = 1 
order by dt desc
limit 1;
```

For performance, you want an index on `(item, dt desc)`.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, that would be:

```
select id, rssi 
from table 
where item = 1  and dt > date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute)
order by rssi desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: I do not need the most recent row.   I need to look at the last min or so of entries and then give me the max rssi out those results.

Comment: Didn't even think about it this way.   I also had another issue related to this and got it figured out by using a view to help out.

Answer (score 0):

You get the max rssi with `max(rssi)`, as the function name suggests :-)

```
select max(rssi)
from table 
where item = 1 and dt > date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute);
```